# What does "fly against" mean?

Tags: vocabulary, phrasal-verbs

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/11/stop-me-if-you-think-youve-seen-this-word-before.html:

> I'm not sure this kind of experiment would fly against
>   today's Google, but it worked in 2004.

What does 'fly against' mean in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Fly against* isn’t functioning as a single phrase here.

To *fly* in this case just means *to work, to be successful*, with a slight connotation that the risk involves skirting the rules of some authority.  *Against* is in the sense of running an experiment *against* some configuration of circumstances.  So the example could be rephrased:

> I’m not sure if running this experiment using today’s Google will work, but it did work in 2004.

---

**Edit:** The [OED](http://www.oed.com) doesn’t document this figurative usage of *fly*, so it’s presumably not just colloquial but also fairly new.  [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fly&page=2) does; it’s currently their eighth-ranked definition for it, with a good example:

> Don't even try that. It ain’t gonna fly.